# Always block execution at time zero

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to execute always block at time zero. 
For e.g. below code won't execute at time zero.

```
always @* begin
//functional code
end
```

I moved sensitivity list at the end so that code will execute at time zero,

```
always begin
//funcitonal code
@*;
end
```

This code executes at time zero but does not execute at all after time zero, even if there is a change in inputs used inside the block. For example see the code below and its output:

```
module AlwaysTimeZeroTest_v();

reg reg_A;

initial begin
  $display ("I'm in Initial begin block       \tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
  #1
  reg_A=1'bZ;

  #1
  reg_A=1'b1;

  #1
  reg_A=1'b0;

  #1
  reg_A=1'bZ;

  #5 $finish;
end

always @* begin
    $display ("I'm in Non-time Zero always block\tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
end

always begin
   $display ("I'm in time Zero always block     \tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
    @*;
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
**I'm in Initial begin block              Time=0.000000, reg_A=x

I'm in time Zero always block           Time=0.000000, reg_A=x

I'm in Non-time Zero always block       Time=1.000000, reg_A=z

I'm in Non-time Zero always block       Time=2.000000, reg_A=1

I'm in Non-time Zero always block       Time=3.000000, reg_A=0

I'm in Non-time Zero always block       Time=4.000000, reg_A=z**
```

Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 9 NS + 0

Can anyone explain why second always block in the code do not execute at all after time zero?

Is there a way I can implement always block so that it executes at time zero without using initial block? (something similar to always_comb in SV?)

Answer (score 6):

Many people do not realize that `@` is a statement modifier, not construct by itself. It says to delay the statement that follows until there is an event. `@(A or B)` means wait until there is a change in the value of `A` or `B` (not to be confused with a change in the result of `A|B`). `@*` means look at the statement that follows, and build an implicit sensitivity list of signals to wait for a change.

In your first `always`, the statement that follows is a `begin/end` block, so `reg_A` gets added to the sensitivity list. In your second `always`, the statement that follows is a *null* statement, so there is no sensitivity to any change.

The only way to make sure that `always @*` executes at time zero is to put some reference to variable in the block that has a change at time 0. Then use a non-blocking assignment to that variable to avoid any time 0 race conditions.

Better yet, use `alway_comb` which was especially designed to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the explanation. Is there an alternative for always_comb in Verilog?

Comment: It depends on the situation that is causing the block not to execute at time 0. One suggestion might be to make sure everything in the sensitivity list is declared as a wire.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this system-verilog so I'll give the answer with respect to that.
If your current usage is `always @*` and you don't drive the outputs from multiple always blocks, use always_comb.  Per LRM, `always_comb` will be executed at time 0.

```
module AlwaysTimeZeroTest_v();

reg reg_A;

initial begin
  $display ("I'm in Initial begin block       \tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
  #1
  reg_A=1'bZ;
  #1
  reg_A=1'b1;
  #1
  reg_A=1'b0;
  #1
  reg_A=1'bZ;
  #5 $finish;
end

always_comb begin
    $display ("I'm in Non-time Zero always block\tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
end

always_comb begin
   $display ("I'm in time Zero always block     \tTime=%f, reg_A=%b\n",$stime,reg_A);
    // @*;
end

endmodule
```