# When this blocks would be executed?

Tags: verilog

1) When this procedural block will be executed?

output a;
reg a;

```
always@(a)
begin
// Do something...
end
```

In C this would be executed when "a" has a value **non-zero**.

2) When this if statement would be true?

```
if(!a)
begin
// Do something...
end
```

I come from C and I'm actually confused about Verilog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always block execution at time zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990457/always-block-execution-at-time-zero)

Comment: `always` is not a procedural statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990457/always-block-execution-at-time-zero/45991654#45991654

Comment: @dave_59 always and initals (and final) blocks **are** procedural blocks. what did you mean?

Comment: @Serge, No, they are not procedural blocks or statements, they are constructs that instantiate procedural blocks or statements. `begin/end` is a procedural block.

Comment: @dave_59 technically you are correct, but lrm (1800)  (in 1.8) defines them as procedural blocks, and (1364) mentions this terminology in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verilog is 4-state simulator, meaning that any bit in a variable could have one of the 4 values: 0, 1, x and z. 'x' expresse an unknown value and all variables in verilog are initialized to this value at the beginning.

now if `a` is initizlized to `x`, the following statements will always fail:

```
if (a) -> because x cannot be true (in verilog)
if (!a) -> false, because !x is also unknown and is x;
```

You should check verilog 4-state simulation  and arithmetic rules.

Always block, on the other hand, will wait till value of 'a' changes, for exemple, from 'x' to '0'.

```
always @(a) ...
```

So, untill you assign `a` value of '1', the 'if' statement will fail and always block will not execute till you change the value of 'a' to something different from 'x'. Initilzation of those variables is usually done in test bench code, say in an initial block. For example

```
 initial #10 a = 1; // initialize 'a' to '1' after 10 time units.
```

Since you coming from 'c', there is a big difference in the language concept. Verilog is a *parallel* programming language, it means that all *procedural* blocks are executed preemptively in parallel. *inital* blocks and *always* blocks are procedural blocks. Statements in side a block are executed sequentially, but two different blocks are executed in parallel.  Events and delays cause preemption.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. It's true procedural blocks execute in parallel. But preemptive behavior is not defined in Verilog. What this means is that a sequential procedural block (statements within a `begin/end` block) execute in order, but there is no defined ordering between statements in different parallel blocks.

Comment: agree, verilog does not define the preemptive behavior, though its behavior is similar. i.e. every #delay will let other scheduled blocks to execute while the current one stops execution in the current cycle and gets scheduled to continue in some future. I guess this way is could be better understood by  a 'c' person :-).